# Group of order 24 is solvable.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solvable-groups

I'm trying to show that any group of order 24 is solvable.
I know $G$ is solvable if and only if both it's normal subgroup $N$ and $G/N$ is solvable. I have proved previously that a group of order 24 has a normal subgroup of order 4 or 8. But I'm stuck.. how do I proceed here? How do I show that $N$ is solvable and $G/N$ is also solvable?

Comment: Then you only need to prove groups of orders $3$, $4$, $6$ and $8$ are soluble.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown can you explain a little further?

Comment: The groups $N$ and $G/N$ will have orders in this list.

Comment: And for the fact (which you have proved), that there is a normal subgroup of order $4$ or $8$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2030980/prove-that-a-group-of-order-24-has-a-normal-subgroup-of-order-4-or-8).