# If $g: G \rightarrow S_4$ is a group homomorphism with $|\ker g|=24$, then the group $G$ is solvable.

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism, sylow-theory, solvable-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Ima}{Im}$ By the first isomorphism theorem of groups, we have that
$$G/\ker g \cong g(G) \leq S_4  $$
Since the group $S_4$ is solvable, we know that every subroup of $S_4$ is solvable. Hence $g(G)$ is solvable, and so is $G/\ker g$.

So, in order to show that $G$ is solvable, it suffices to show that $\ker g$ is solvable.

We have $|\ker g|=24=2^33$. So:

$$n_3 \equiv 1 \pmod 3 \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \ n_3 \ | \ 8,$$
$$n_2 \equiv 1 \pmod 2 \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \ n_2 \ | \ 3,$$
where $n_3$ represents the number of Sylow $3$-subgroups of $\ker g$, and $n_2$ represents the number of Sylow $2$-subgroups of $\ker g$. Hence $n_3 = 1$ or $n_3=4$ and  $n_2 = 1$ or $n_2=3$.

If $n_3 = 1$, then there is a unique Sylow $3$-subgroup, $P_3$, which is a normal subroup of $\ker g$.

So we have the subnormal series

$$\{1\} \trianglelefteq P_3 \trianglelefteq \ker g $$

from which we can conclude that the group $\ker g$ is solvable, since  $|\ker g / P_3|=8=2^3$ is a prime power, hence the group $\ker g / P_3$ is abelian.

Similarly, one could prove that $\ker g$ is solvable if $n_2 = 1$.

The problem is, I don't know how to exclude the case $n_3 = 4$ and $n_2 = 3$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is a duplicate here, that a group of order $24$ is solvable - see for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2775186/group-of-order-24-is-solvable?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: If $n_2=3$, then the action on the Sylow subgroups by conjugation gives you a homomorphism to $S_3$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Unfortunately, the (eventual) duplicate target simply asserts that groups of order less than $60$ are solvable; then the OP would not need the considerations in the first place.

Comment: I think that this site has several posts showing that all groups of order $n<60$ are solvable. I haven't checked all of them (they are too many), how detailed or useful they are. For example, they should not use Burnside's $p^aq^b$- result of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N=\mathrm{ker}(G)$. Assume $n_2=3$. Then $N$ acts by conjugation on the set of $2$-Sylow subgroups, yielding a homomorphism $N\to S_3$. Because the action is transitive, the image cannot be trivial; the image must be either $A_3$ (cyclic of order $3$) or all of $S_3$. In both cases we have a solvable image, so again we can just go down to the kernel. If the image is cyclic of order $3$, then the kernel is of order $8$, and being a $2$-group, it is solvable (nontrivial center). If the image has order $6$, then the kernel has order $4$ and so must be abelian, hence solvable.

Comment: Hi! I have two questions:
First, why can't the image of the homomorphism be of order 2?
And second, what do you mean by "going down to the kernel?"
Thanks!

Comment: @J.Spi: Image can't be of order $2$ because the subgroups of order $2$ are not transitive. (But even if the image were of order $2$, it would be solvable and the argument could proceed; but it can't be).Given a group $G$ and normal subgroup $N$ of $G$, it is well-known that $G$ is solvable if and only if both $N$ and $G/N$ are solvable. Here, we know that $G/N$ is solvable, so the solvability of $G$ depends only on establishing the solvability of $N$; that is, "going down" to just looking at $N$.

Comment: Thank you for your time.